# Adding UI components dynamically to my Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create components on the fly, so, I know how to make this, but, how can I  access this component on the fly?

For example:

```
    public Form1
    {
        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        label1.Name = string.Format("label{0}", labelsCount.ToString());
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label1.TabIndex = 2;
        label1.Text = string.Format("Label -> {0}", labelsCount.ToString());
        label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
        label1.BringToFront();
        label1.Show();
        labelsCount++;
    }
```

When I click on the label, I want to get the label's information (like position, text and name)

How I can do this? Or, what is the best way to do this?

And, to access the component based on position of the panel, inside of form, how I can do this?

Comment: Please change your title and update your tags. Your title does not match the question, and your tags should list which GUI toolkit (Windows Forms, it seems) you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sender of event is your lablel. Simply cast sender object to `Label` type:

```
void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    // use
    // label.Name
    // label.Location
}
```